# parse json from url using php and save in mysql db

Tags: php, json

I've a JSON response from some web service

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1503291248,
  "quotes":{
    "SAD":"ABC",
    "LOVE":"XYZ",
    "FRIENDSHIP":"SOME",
    "ENMITY":"LOREM IPSUM",
    ... //indicates there are a lot more categories
  }
}
```

I have tried to echo data using this script

```
<?php
    $url = 'MY_URL';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    foreach ( $json as $idx=>$json ) {
       echo $idx;
    }
?>
```

this  prints

```
successtermsprivacytimestampsourcequotes
```

but getting empty response, how can I echo/save above josn data in mySql?

Comment: what is "Position" ? can not see in json array ?

Comment: You should get undefined variable for $obj. I cannot see it anywhere in your code. Please paste whole code first.

Comment: I'm new to PHP universe and was flowing a tutorial , don't have any idea!

Comment: I think it should be `foreach ( $json as $key=>$value)`. You're using `$json` twice in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $url = '{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1503291248,
  "quotes":{
    "SAD":"ABC",
    "LOVE":"XYZ",
    "FRIENDSHIP":"SOME",
    "ENMITY":"LOREM IPSUM",
    ... //indicates there are a lot more categories
  }
}';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    foreach ( $json as $idx=>$json ) {
       if(is_array($json))
       {
         foreach($json as $iidx=>$jjson) 
         {
             echo $iidx.":".$jjson;
         }
       }
       else
       {
         echo $idx.":".$json;
       }
    }

    $ins_qry = 'INSERT INTO json_table(jsonvalues) values ("'.$json.'")';
    $exec_qry = mysqli_query($link,$ins_qry);
?>
```

This will print json data.
To save this json data in mysql, you can directly insert the `$json` value into text column of a MySQL table.

Comment: O Man! it worked but not correct, it prints `success:1timestamp:1503294550quotes:Array`, how to fix the issue of `quotes:Array` I want to insert each item of array in `cate_name = SAD and value = ABC` and so on?

Comment: Great! it needs some more modifications on my side but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$url = 'MY_URL';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ( $json as $val) {
    echo $val['success']; //same for other keys
}
```

Comment: it echos hhU don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token;
```